# Allow close votes on Stack Overflow meta questions using an appropriate duplicate question from Stack Exchange meta site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

Why can't we close meta.stackoverflow questions with duplicates from meta.stackexchange if the duplicate is a near-perfect fit?

If I am remembering things correctly, meta.stackoverflow was the site's original meta, and meta.stackexchange came later to address more general site-wide meta issues. It seems obvious that a good fraction of questions asked on the individual meta sites would be fully addressed and answered by similar questions on the general question site, and so it would make sense to allow us to propose to close the question using the Stack Exchange duplicate.

The question that triggered this question was this closed/deleted meta.stackoverflow question: *[Why you can't un-upvote or un-downvote if the last revision was already more than five minutes ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376579/why-cant-you-un-upvote-or-un-downvote-if-the-last-revision-was-already-more-tha)*.

Here is an image for those who can't see deleted questions:

[image]

I wanted to vote to close it using a decent Stack Exchange meta duplicate: *[Why do votes get locked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked)*, but since the site wouldn't allow me to do this, I manually typed in a comment that mimics close voting.

So my proposal: allow us to vote to close specific meta questions with appropriate duplicates found on the Stack Exchange meta site.

*Or, should I be asking this on the meta.stackexchange site*?

Comment: [*Maybe* this is better suited on Meta.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=cross-site+dupe)

Comment: @Makoto: indeed. Migrate it, perhaps?

Comment: @Servy: I was looking for a duplicate, but darned if I could find it. Thank you

Comment: But having said that, I still disagree with the solution in the duplicate and think that this feature *should* be allowed

Comment: It's my question that i deleted...

Comment: @u9for yes I know, but I was asking about the general case and just using your post as an example